# What does data (->) a b mean?

Tags: haskell, ghci

For (->) we have:

```
Prelude> :i (->)
data (->) t1 t2         -- Defined in ‘GHC.Prim’
```

What does this syntax mean? I thought the data declaration keyword required a type constructor on the LHS and one or more value constructors on the RHS?

And how is (->) generally spoken or pronounced?

Comment: `(+) a b` is equivalent to `a + b` at the expression level.  `(->) a b` is equivalent to `a -> b` at the type level.  Wrapping an infix expression in parentheses is how you write it in prefix.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`(->)` is the function type and people generally pronounce it as "to" (ie `a -> b` would be pronounced "a to b").

`(->)` is a primitive construct built into GHC: the compiler handles it specially. However, some tools like `:i` that work with normal types see a fake definition of `(->)` as if it was an empty data type:

```
data (->) a b
```

This allows `:i` to give you information about a built-in operation as if it was a normal definition.

The `(->) a b` syntax is the prefix version of an infix name, just like you can define normal operators in prefix form:

```
a ~+ b = a * b + b
```

is the same as

```
(~+) a b = a * b + b
```

If you actually tried defining `(->)` this way yourself, you would get an error:

```
<interactive>:20:1-13: error:
    Illegal binding of built-in syntax: (->)
```

However, you *can* define empty data types like this yourself if you give them a valid name:

```
data Foo a b
```

This makes `Foo` a type with two (phantom) arguments that has no values except ⊥, just like `Void` from `Data.Void`.

If you want to play around with the infix syntax, you can define a type operator with the `TypeOperators` extension enabled, with the same meaning as `Foo`:

```
data a +~ b
```

or

```
data (+~) a b
```

This might be useful if, for example, we want to emulate OCaml and write pair typess as `a * b` rather than `(a, b)`:

```
type a * b = (a, b)
```